# module configuration function is not being called if the .component() is called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components

I have two files in my angular app as shown below:

1. module.js

   ```
   (function () {

   "use strict";

   var module = angular.module("psMovies", ["ngRoute"]);

   module.config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {

   $routeProvider
       .when("/list", { template: "<movie-list></movie-list>" })
       .when("/about", { template: "<app-about></app-about>" });
   }]);

   })();
   ```
2. movie-list.component.js

   ```
   (function () {

   var module = angular.module("psMovies", ["ngRoute"]);

   module.component("movieList", {
       template: "List goes here..."
   });

   })();
   ```

with this, I am not seeing the config function is hitting at all. if I remove `module.component()` in second file, then the config function is hitting successfully.

Could someone please explain why `.component()` is blocking the function execution inside `.config()`, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file `module.js`, you already inject `ngRoute`
So you only need to call `var module = angular.module("psMovies");` in the second file
It's not problem in `module.component()`